# How can I calculate the most recent 12 months' average and most recent 4 quarters' average in a same table

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, average

[image: image description]

Above is a dataframe I made.

You can see the "open" and "close" were recorded quarterly,
but "recoveryRate" was recorded monthly.

I need to calculate the quarterly avg. (avg of the most recent 4 quarrers) of "open" and "close",
and I also need to calculate the monthly avg. (avg of the most recent 12 months) of "recoveryRate"

How can I achieve it in Python

Comment: you can use python `datetime`

Comment: Please do not add images of code or data. It's useless as it's impossible to copy anything in order to test. Add your data as properly formatted code block.